# Can't hide NSSplitView divider

Tags: cocoa, show-hide, nssplitview

I have a split view that looks like:

| source | filter | list | detail |

I want to programmatically hide the filter so in my NSSplitView delegate I use

```
-(BOOL)splitView:(NSSplitView *)splitView shouldHideDividerAtIndex:(NSInteger)dividerIndex
```

To hide the filter section I am using

```
[[[[self splitView] subviews] objectAtIndex:1] setHidden:YES];
[[self splitView] adjustSubviews];
```

Before hiding:
[image]
After hiding:
[image]

I have made the dividers red in my subclass to more easily see what is happening. Both dividers are still there - right next to each other, but the one on the right should disappear completely.

Is this happening because I am trying to hide a subview that is not at the edge? Perhaps it only works for index 0 and max?

How can I make this work?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Nope - I have basically given up making it work like I want.

Comment: I made it work, have a looksie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60165351/hiding-dividers-in-nssplitview

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to just set proper position of divider:

```
 splitView.setPosition(splitView.bounds.width, ofDividerAtIndex: 0)
```

And also override another delegate method to allow collapsing your view:

```
    func splitView(splitView: NSSplitView, canCollapseSubview subview: NSView) -> Bool {
    //You may choose which view you allow to collapse here...
    return true
}

func splitView(splitView: NSSplitView, shouldHideDividerAtIndex dividerIndex: Int) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

I created a test project for you here:

https://github.com/emankovski/CollapseSplitViews

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Nope - that does not affect it. I am also having a problem with the objects in the collapsed view getting their positioning constraints messed up probably  because the width is going to zero.