# Hiding Dividers in NSSplitView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Since `NSSplitView` doesn't allow for hiding its dividers (the delegate method only allows for hiding dividers that are on the split views edge), I chose to subclass `NSSplitView` and override its draw methods to prevent specific dividers from drawing.

However, as soon as I override either `draw(rect:)` or `drawDivider(in:)` the `NSSplitView` no longer animates it's dividers if I collapse an item like so

```
activityItem.animator().isCollapsed = collapsed
```

It even happens if I call `super` directly without adding my own drawing code

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)
}
```

The code above is enough to completely break animations.

Basically all I am trying to achieve is hiding a split view item alongside its divider, but that is apparently too much to ask of a `NSSplitView` without reimplementing it completely.

I'm on my last straw here. Any other method to accomplish hiding items + divider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I went a whole different way and found a way to make it work. So if you are trying to completely customize dividers this is how you do it.

1. Subclass `NSSplitView` and return `0` from `dividerThickness`

So your new split view won't display dividers at all now, but you can add them manually where you want them

2. Add `NSBox` or your custom divider views where you want your dividers to show up in your split view subviews, preferrably at the top of the subview.
3. Override the split view delegate method `splitView(:additionalEffectiveRectOfDividerAt:)` and manually return rects that match your custom `NSBox` dividers

You might need to `convert(:from:)` between `NSView` coordinates to get your effective rects, but it works! The delegate might look something like this

```
override func splitView(_ splitView: NSSplitView, additionalEffectiveRectOfDividerAt dividerIndex: Int) -> NSRect {
    let item = splitViewItems[dividerIndex]
    let itemView = item.viewController.view
    let frame = view.convert(itemView.bounds, from: itemView)

    let dividerFrame = CGRect(x: 0,
                              y: view.bounds.height - frame.minY,
                              width: frame.width,
                              height: 1)

    return dividerFrame
}
```

There you have it. Custom dividers that also work with animations!